# Move command with Exclusion

Tags: batch-file

I have folder tree.

d:\A\AA\AAA\

d:A\AA\BBB\

Now Inside that AAA and BBB I have again 15-20 Sub folders which will share common names in both AAA and BBB.
Inside that folder I Have few files from CSV and Excel.

Now what I want to do is, I want to pick each of the file and create another subfolder having Systemdate as a name and move respective file in that date folder.

So now new folder structure will be.
d:\A\AA\AAA\Subfolders\15032017\
d:A\AA\BBB\Subfolders\15032017\

Now what I want is next time when this script will execute again it will skip 15032017 folder and check only files which are in Subfolders

I tried this code but got stuck. (:: Comment out as was not working as expected)

How to exclude checking folder which is created using SDate(e.g- for `15th March` folder is `15032017`)

Adding My Script below. As asked!

```
@Echo Off
::Variable for folder path

for /r D:\A\ %%i in (*.xls) do SET "FPath=%%~dpi"

::FOR %%i IN ("%myh%") DO Set filedrive=%%~dpi

:: SDate=DAYMONTHYEAR FORMAT of Systemdate
set SDate=%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%%date:~10,4%

::ROBOCOPY D:\Source D:\Dest * /MOV /XF *.xls

if not exist %FPath%\%SDate% mkdir %FPath%\%SDate%
move %FPath%\* %FPath%\%SDate%

set "FPath="
Echo Now %FPath%
::set "SDate="
```

Comment: The `for /r `will inevitably dive into the newly created subfolder and probably have multiple results from which the set will only return the very last one, so you should elaborate a bit more what the whole batch's task is.

Comment: I need to create one script where it will check on every 2 hours weather new file is added on Sub Folders. If there is file available then it will check weather we have Date Folder(As mention in question) if not create one and move that file in new created folder. So file will get sorted according to date folder. Now what limitation I am facing is next time when It will check files it will skip Folders on Date Name. And as I have multiple sub folders. My file path is noit fix(Hard Coded)

Comment: Well that really was only a bit. I suggest you edit your question to include the whole batch. It's unclear to me how  the move will help the check for new files. And when you know the subfolder why evaluate it through a for /r?

Comment: @LotPings added my script I created so far..!

Comment: The confusion grows :-( The `for /r`will get you the last folder containing an xls file, presumably the one with sdate appended - so it's still impossible to guess what you are after. BTW the commented out robocopy command with totally different drive/folder doesn't help.

Comment: You should perhaps show your folder structure (by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42807011/edit) your question) and include example when you want to move a file and when not, because your question is a bit confusing...

Comment: @LotPing and Aschipfl- I tried to asked my question last time in detail. That time some one told this is not free coding site and top of that putted my question on hold stating it contains too many Information/Question. Still will try to put question again hope this time I will get solution...! :-(